# Allow user to review FB.api call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a web application that will let the user to upload an image to their Facebook profile. As of now, my code makes sure the user is logged in and has given publish_actions permissions to the app and, if so, automatically makes the upload/post.

I would like to force the user to review and confirm (or deny) the FB.api action before it is sent to Facebook. Does the Facebook SDK allow for this flow in API calls?

I'm aware that FB.ui allows for review, but it also seems that FB.ui allows only sharing and cannot handle photo uploads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, FB.api just does the call, there is no confirmation implemented in the API. You would have to do that on your own before calling FB.api.